# How do I remove this soffit?

Tags: siding, soffit

I have seen wasps going up into my soffit. I want to take down my soffit, deal with any nests, and replace the soffit. Presumably, I'll add some wire mesh and caulk where necessary to seal any gaps to prevent future infestations.

My problem is that I have gutter in front of the fascia, and drip edge leading into the gutter. Do I have to remove the drip edge and the gutter to deal with this? If so, that is a much bigger job than I am willing to take on. Is there an easier way to remove it? It appears to be attached with roofing nails in every other groove at the front edge.

[image: The site where I have seen wasps entering...]

[image: Drip edge to gutter]

[image: Roofing nails securing soffit]

Comment: Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have two general options: Remove the fascia, or get bendy.

Soffit like that is installed after an F-channel on the wall and before the fascia (technically a fascia *cover*). You'd have to remove the fascia, which obviously involves removing the gutter first. You don't need to mess with the drip edge at all--just make sure the fascia is behind it when replaced.

Alternatively, loosen the gutter and fascia in an area and flex it out enough to expose the soffit edge. You'll probably find fasteners there, so remove them. Now you can wiggle out one segment at a time of the soffit. Do your best to not kink any metal.

Frankly I'd do a little spraying *through* the soffit and see how that does. You could even enlarge a perforation here or there to get a nozzle through.

Comment: Not odd at all. I've done a number of retrofits like that. It's fairly easy to cut out a strip of the old plywood for airflow and overlay aluminum or vinyl.

Comment: Looking at the second photo, it looks like there's a J-channel piece of vinyl trim on the back side of the fascia that supports the outer edge of the soffit.

Comment: The second photo shows rain gutter and roof edge. The third photo shows what I assume to be the hem/wraparound on the bottom of the fascia.